# py2neo: Get the get the end nodes from relationships and all incoming relationships without cypher

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I having trouble finding the node that an node is in a relationship with.
I want to be able to find the nodes with a relationship with selected node from the selected node.

[Here is an example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj67o.png)

Here is the code for the example graph:

```
from py2neo import Node, Relationship, Graph, NodeSelector, Path
from py2neo.ogm import *
graph = Graph(user = 'neo4j', password = 'neo4j')
graph.delete_all()

class Man(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "name"
    name = Property("name")
    likes = RelatedTo("Woman", "LIKES")

class Woman(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "name"
    name = Property("name")
    likes = RelatedTo("Man", "LIKES")

new_man = Man()
new_man.name = "John"
graph.push(new_man)

new_woman = Woman()
new_woman.name = "Sarah"
new_woman.likes.add(Man.select(graph, primary_value="John").first())
graph.push(new_woman)

new_man = Man()
new_man.name = "Joe"
new_man.likes.add(Woman.select(graph, primary_value="Sarah").first())
graph.push(new_man)
```

My attempt at getting the name of who Sarah likes:

```
sarah = Woman.select(graph, primary_value="Sarah").first()
sarah.likes._related_objects[0][0].name
# returns "John"
# or
list(sarah.__ogm__.related.values())[0]._related_objects[0][0].name
# returns "John"
```

I was unable to find any way of getting the name of who likes Sarah without looking at the other nodes.  Is this possible or am I wasting my time?  Are there better ways to do any of this?
Am I stuck with:

```
def get_who_likes_sarah():
    names = []
    for m in Man.select(graph):
        try:
            name = m.likes._related_objects[0][0].name
            if name == "Sarah":
                names.append(m.name)
        except:
            pass
    return names
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Gave up and stayed with what I had. My code ended up with something like this in it
`[m.name for m in Man.select(graph) for w in m.likes._related_objects if w[0].name == "Sarah"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should get it by doing this:

```
for rel in graph.match(start_node=sarah, rel_type="LIKES"):
    names.append(rel.end_node()["name"])
```